# filtering huggingface dataset on sagemaker crashes

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-datasets

given a dataset like

```
from datasets import load_dataset
gtzan = load_dataset("marsyas/gtzan", "all")
```

I should be able to filter it like

```
gtzan['train'].filter(lambda x: x['file'] == gtzan['train']['file'][0])
```

at least that works perfectly on colab

but doing the same given the installing corresponding libraries I get

[image]

while having the following for 10-15 seconds

[image]

could it be because it can not load those widgets ?!

I am using `ml.t3.medium` instance type along with `Pytorch 2.0.1 Python 3.10 CPU` Image.